# Recursively count lines of code, excluding empty lines and comments

Tags: code-golf, counting, file-system, recursion

**Requirement:** Write a program (in any language) that counts the number of lines of code in files matching `*.sh` in the directory tree starting from the directory that the program is executed in, excluding lines that are empty, only contain whitespace, or are just single-line comments (a line which the first character that is not a whitespace character is `#`). Files will only contain printable ASCII characters.

**Output:** A single integer representing the total count (can be followed by a newline too).

Here is an expanded solution in Python:

```
import os, sys

def recurse(dir = './'):
    count = 0

    for file in os.listdir(dir):
        if not os.path.isfile(dir + file):
            count += recurse(dir + file + '/')
        elif file.endswith('.sh'):
            with open(dir + file, 'r') as f:
                for line in f.read().split('\n'):
                    if (not line.strip().startswith('#')) and (not line.strip() == ''):
                        count += 1

    return count

sys.stdout.write(recurse())
```

Comment: _Files will only contain printable ASCII characters._ -- can a file contain a `/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Powershell 3+, 40 byte

```powershell
(ls *.sh -r|sls '^\s*(#|$)' -a -n).Count
```

`ls *.sh -r` gets a file names from the directory tree. `sls` (alias for [Select-String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String)) gets all strings (`-a` is shortcut for `-AllMatches`) that not mathces (`-n` is alias for `-NotMatch`) to the pattern `'^\s*(#|$)'`.

Comment: Side note: `().Count` was introduced in PowerShell 3; in PowerShell 2 you can use `|measure` instead although that also tries to give you other measurements not relevant here.

Comment: I'm agree `(....|measure).Count`. But [Powershell 2 is deprecated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/08/24/windows-powershell-2-0-deprecation/) since the summer 2017. I'm not sure the version `3+` requires an explicit statement. In any case, I've specified the version. Thanks.

Comment: Ah! I keep forgetting about `Select-String`! Nice solution.

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```powershell
ls *.sh -r|gc|%{$o+=!($_-match'^\s*(#|$)')};$o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/P6dYQUuvOENBt6gmPblGtVolX9tWUUMlXjc3sSQ5Qz0uplhLQ7lGRVNds9ZaJf//fwA) (will always return `0` since there aren't any files)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvlJafn5BXklpckpCnnJyfm5uaV6JkBxTUK874n1OsoAWkFXSLatKTa1SrVfK1bRU1VOJ1cxNLkjPU42KKtTSUa1Q01TVrrVXy//8HAA) (here's a link that populates a dummy file so you can see the process)

*-1 byte thanks to Neil*

`ls` is alias for `Get-ChildItem`, specifying `*.sh` with the `-r`ecurse parameter, then we `g`et-`c`ontent of files. For each of those lines `|%{...}`, we accumulate into our `$o`utput a one if the Boolean `!(...)` statement is truthy. Inside the statement is a simple regex `-match` against the whitespace-only/comment/blank lines. Finally we leave `$o` on the pipeline.

<s>The implicit `Write-Output` that happens at program completion adds a trailing newline, but that shouldn't matter in this case because the variable `$o` itself doesn't have a trailing newline nor does the actual return variable. It's a quirk of the shell, not a quirk of the program. For example, saving this to a script and executing that script in a pipeline will not have a newline.</s>

Comment: You can write `$-notmatch'^\s*(#|$)'` instead `!($_-match'^\s*(#|$)')`. The length is same. But expression is more clear.

Comment: `ls *.sh -r|gc|` saves a byte.

Comment: Thanks @Neil - nice catch.

Answer (score 3):

## Linux Shell, <s>30</s> 60 bytes

confirmed in `dash`

```
cat `find . -name \*.sh`|tr -d " \t"|grep .|grep -v ^#|wc -l
```

1. `find . -name \*.sh`: find files matching the pattern, list with path
2. `cat ''`: list contents of these files
3. `tr -d " \t"`: trim tabs and spaces
4. `grep .`: remove empty lines
5. `grep -v ^#`: remove comments
6. `wc -l`: count lines of output

Comment: the comment `#` can be found after spaces.

Comment: @mazzy, nope, after `tr -d " \t"` they can not.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>70</s>  64 bytes

```r
sum(!grepl("^(#|$)",unlist(lapply(dir(,".sh$",r=T),readLines))))
```

Explanation:

The `dir` function has the `recursive` flag set.

`readLines` returns the lines of a file in a vector, which are then flattened with `unlist`.

Comment: I haven't tested it... but can you save bytes by using `grepl`, adding a `!` and getting rid of `|1` and of `inv=T`?

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>211</s> 210 bytes

```
import System.Directory
f x=listDirectory x>>=fmap sum.mapM(\d->doesFileExist d>>=(#d)).map((x++"/")++)
p#d|p=do c<-readFile d;pure$sum[1|take 3(reverse d)=="hs.",(q:_):_<-map words$lines c,q/='#']|1<2=f d
f"."
```

Oh dear, without shell glob and regex you have to do all the work by yourself. Maybe there's somewhere a module for it. Also, IO code in Haskell requires some overhead to get the types right.

```
f x =                             -- main function, expects a directory 'x'
    listDirectory x >>=           -- read content of directory (without "." and "..")
              map((x++"/")++)     --   for each entry: prepend current directory 'x' and a slash
          mapM(\d->doesFileExist d>>=(#d))
                                  --   for each entry: call function '#' with
                                  --        first parameter: a boolean, True if it's a regular file, False if it's a directory
                                  --        second parameter: the filename itself
                                  --        '#' returns a list of valid lines for each file
     fmap sum                     --   sum this list

p#d
   |p                             -- if 'p' is True (i.e. 'd' is regular file)
     do c<-readFile d;            --   read the content 'c' of file 'd' and 
        pure$sum[1|      ]        --   return the number of lines
              take 3(reverse d)=="hs."
                                  --     (only if the file end with .sh)
              (q:_):_<-map words$lines c,q/='#'
                                  --     where the first word doesn't start with a hash sign
                                  --       (function 'words' strips leading whitespace)
   |1<2                           -- else ('d' is a directory)
       =f d                       --   examine d

f"."                              -- start with current directory
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 55

```bash
find . -name \*.sh -exec cat {} +|grep -Evc '^\s*(#|$)'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGBCYAgFAXAVR4UWIY6RVtIYF/LwCy0Iqhmt7vRZF/IQp05qbCRCWVaooWEiGZ10FxmD@FuRyBz4PnQvXNyO0R/EdigM2@qt25ZKT8)

Comment: Does `find . -name \*.sh|xargs cat|grep -Evc '^\s*(#|$)'` work?

Comment: Or even `cat **/*.sh|...`, though it needs *globstar* to be turned on (or a different shell such as *zsh*, *csh/tcsh*).. Not sure if you'd need to include it in your bytecount.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch + Internal tools, <s>80</s> 76 Bytes

```
@for /F %%F IN ('findstr/SV "^\s*# ^\s*$" *.sh^|find/C":"')DO @set/P=%%F<NUL
```

Uses the builtin `findstr` to fetch the lines, then counts these line using `find /C`.

This however produces output with a newline, so we need to convert that into an output without. This is done by using `for /F` to fetch the output and then use `<NUL set /P` to output without the trailing newline.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>149</s> <s>146</s> <s>144</s> <s>140</s> <s>149</s> <s>146</s> 116 bytes

```python
import os
print sum(l.strip()[:1]not in'#'for a,b,c in os.walk(".")for n in c for l in open(a+"/"+n)if'.sh'==n[-3:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZDBboMwDIbvPIVHD05UGgS9IfVJSg@BhpEV7CjJhLaXZ0m1w9TrfLH9O/Znx33Fmand7erYR@BQFBzU@rhbL1DVE3ONsig2G2dgZyiLg/YqzFgBbihBB5iaroBkU6M2b6MR2BOqD7YkBGqs8ADEcbb0DpEhGAOz8SbpqWd8S76PfYTk7yjlKy2vMOjvF2L7S2z/TazQZOqfH3DeUoTwuYpFheitE/LaNbc0ECzhASf2oKuhGlOa3qtNLw9RqlLmAmVxhBwuz3o@Qx/LujyStBPmOy4Xup7O3U3u@w8)

<s>Reports 0 on TIO but works locally. Probably not any `.sh` files in whatever is the current directory.</s>

I think it now works correctly on TIO and fixed a bug for +6, both thanks to @JonathanAllen

-30 with thanks to @ovs

Alternative for **139 bytes** but only works on Windows.

```python
import os
os.system('dir/s/b *.sh>f')
print sum(sum((0,1)[x.strip()>''and'#'!=x.strip()[0]]for x in open(l[2:].strip()))for l in open("f"))
```

Creates a temporary file `f` to store the results for the `dir` command.

Comment: You can [create some files at TIO](https://tio.run/##pZDBbsMgEETv/opNcliQHBK7t0juj9g@kBpqEnvXAiqr/fkU0qiqci0SGjEa9g0sn3Fkqm9uXthH4FAUHNR8HZwXqA6W@YCyKFYXR@DFUDbP2qswYgm4ogQdwFanAtKylVq9i0ZgR6gu7EgI1FjiDojj6OgdIkMwBkbjTfLTnbdN0i52EZIOKOUzLVc4668nYv0g1v8mlmgy9c8PLN5RhPAxi7zFsXxIJdtJhejdIuQroqYBd7hpfr322PeWPUzg6Kc@pcEttfuXU980mJ9wD1AO2HZf9TIf7T0f1Kqnq9iqbSpz@wY). Unfortunately that shows up a bug - I believe you'd need to `open(os.path.join(a_path_prefix, n))` for it to actually work (although just using `+` will of course be golfier!))

Comment: `(0,1)[l.strip()>''and'#'!=l.strip()[0]]` can become `all([l.strip()>'','#'!=l.strip()[0:]])` to save 1 byte.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanAllan. Will delete for now as I don't have time to fix.

Comment: @mypetlion - thanks but temporarily deleted due to a bug spotted by JonathanAllan

Comment: That's impressive, nice job. I tried to cut off a byte or two, but couldn't think of any way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. Some serious help from @ovs to lose 30 bytes at the end tho so credit and respect due.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 61 bytes

```ruby
p Dir.glob("**/*.sh").sum{|x|open(x).grep(/^\s*[^#\s]/).size}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxDoIwGATg/X@KQodCY9qFsW4@gomDSAKmQCMK6Q@xSnn2WrkbbvnOLs0nuKNSBZx7g2CQ1DBrnIHEACWxQOilr@@PBPahCRQA46RfGftLgT07sDfLV9/6Vim3hYmcjBXdMDZZyrnkkaS5wOW5euf3p8tFZ/WUyapEfq1oiTcZhfnqLYQf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda) + find, 98 bytes

```
{bufferedExec"find",".","-name","*.sh"|{|x|try readLines x}_|{|x|x~=`\s|#.*`,"";[1]if[#x>0]}_|sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8pPSfyfm5iZp1D9vzqpNC0ttSg1xbUiNVkpLTMvRUlHSQ@IdfMSc1OBtJZecYZSTXVNRU1JUaVCUWpiik9mXmqxQkVtPFi0os42Iaa4RllPK0FHSck62jA2My1aucLOIBaooLg0t/Z/7X8A)

## Pure Röda, 129 bytes

```
{["."]|[_]if isFile(_1)else unpull(x)for x in[ls(_1)]|{|x|try readLines x if[x=~`.*\.sh`]}_|{|l|l~=`\s|#.*`,"";[1]if[#l>0]}_|sum}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc3RCoMgFIDhVxG7qRiyrke73NXewESDjAknG54Eh6de3dX1/8Ef1mksy@g8yyVLLrgiqZWbmcOXA1vrrrGAlkX/jQB1auY1sMScl4BXVJQp0RZ@LNhxejtv8cqzTP1hRDsI/Bi161MBwdGbAakSrblx/pDd@ZEVPO8XwLjsZS9/)

Explanation:

```
{
["."]|                     /* Push "." to the stream */
                           /* For each _1 in the stream: */
[_]if isFile(_1)           /*   If _1 is a file, push it to the output stream */
else                       /*   Else (if _1 is a directory): */
unpull(x)for x in[ls(_1)]| /*     Push each file/dir in _1 to the *input stream* */
{|x|                       /* For each x in the stream: */
  try readLines x          /*   Push lines of x to the stream ignoring errors */
    if[x=~`.*\.sh`]        /*     if x ends in .sh */
}_|
{|l|                       /* For each l in the stream: */
  l~=`\s|#.*`,"";          /*   Remove whitespace and comments from l */
  [1]if[#l>0]              /*   Push 1 to the stream if l is not empty */
}_|
sum                        /* Sum all numbers in the stream */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>248</s> 209 bytes

```c
#import <regex.h>
*l,i,j;*k;regex_t r;f(n,s,t){if(fnmatch("*.sh",n,0))return 0;k=fopen(n,"r");for(regcomp(&r,"^\\s*(#|$)",1);i=getline(&l,&i,k)>0;)regexec(&r,l,0,0,0)&&j++;}main(){ftw(".",f,1);printf("%d",j);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3BboMwEETv/Qq0Sa1dskX0vE2@JEqFXBsMZkHGVSOl@XYSormN5r2xHzY22q7rLozzlHLxlVzrrlV3eisjB@6lHORVfeciiUflhTPdgkevY5Nth1BWSwesXBMll3@TFrUMRz/NTp9zSEDip4RPi53GGU1iuJzPS4m7/z0Bf5KEY@tyDOrQRDaBBzrVQq9bZzcgcr2FjOkPB7mPTVCkm89/CBWw3xxzCpo9wvsPcE9yX9cH)

Comment: Save one byte `char i,j,*l;` ==> `char*l,i,j;`

Comment: 189 Bytes [here](https://bit.ly/2zwxKy9)

Comment: Why are you not counting your definition and include bytes?

Comment: @JonathanFrech, because it's just an argument, it could be any directory

Comment: I do not think that is legal I/O; some inclusions you perform are necessary and not counted.

Comment: See [this default I/O consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/73111).

Comment: Suggest `#import<regex.h>` instead of `#include <regex.h>`. Also, can ditch `ftw.h` and `fnmatch.h`

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>105 140 174 186 184</s> 172 bytes

```php
function f($d){foreach(glob("$d/*")as$n)$n[strlen($d)+1]^_^A&&$s+=!is_dir($n)?fnmatch("*.sh",$n)?preg_match_all("/^\s*[^#]/m",join(file($n))):0:f($n);return$s;}echo f(".");
```

skips hidden directories and files (name starts with a dot). Run with `-nr`.

### breakdown

```php
function f($d)
{
    # loop through directory entries
    foreach(glob("$d/*")as$n)
        # if name does not start with a dot
        $n[strlen($d)+1]^_^A
        # then increase sum:
        &&$s+=
            # not a directory?
            !is_dir($n)
                # filename matches pattern?
                ?fnmatch("*.sh",$n)
                    # count lines that are neither empty nor begin with a "#"
                    ?preg_match_all("/^\s*[^#]/m",join(file($n)))
                    # else 0
                    :0
                # is a directory: recurse
                :f($n)
        ;
    return$s;
}
echo f(".");
```

---

I could save two more bytes with `fnmatch()*preg_match_all()` instead of `fnmatch()?preg_match_all():0`;
and then another one with `is_dir()?B:A` instead of `!is_dir()?A:B`;
but that could make it insanely slow.

Comment: `substr($n,-3)=='.sh'` would be shorter than `preg_match("/\.sh$/",$n)`.

Comment: Sorry, actually `fnmatch('*.sh',$n)` is even shorter.

Comment: @manatwork Wow I didn´t even know that function!

Comment: Yepp, weird thing. I only found out about it after used the similar [`File.fnmatch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html#method-c-fnmatch) in Ruby for years.

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 57 bytes

```sh
for f (**/*.sh(D))a+=(${${(f)"$(<$f)"//[ 	]}%%#*})
<<<$#a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU1BasMwEDxHr5hGSiy7xIKcVZ@aXvuAtoe1I2ORWDKWoCEhb3eXtrQLwywzuzPXNCzj6ehn7CbUZFojXDdEqCIPbnYgRv6M7@Hsg0sFmp@jmuo0iAYtE6xFcXh9KYR8MK0Phh2JLo6jC1ngdyTSRJ1LYiWRqWWdl9Ff3FGEmNmmvxcJn76F/xSOX/o4o4euKlNxq34uS3p80uqmbrov10pbxWTMG1Yf981GVvdSWGuVpGWafcjYnaEIzXa/fAE)

Almost beat bash+coreutils with native zsh constructs.

```sh
for f (**/*.sh(D))                    # the (D) flag enables globdots
   a+=(${${(f)"$(<$f)"//[   ]}%%#*})
 #       ${(f)"$(<$f)"       }        # read in file, split on newlines
 #       ${           //[   ]}        # remove all spaces and tabs
 #     ${                     %%#*}   # remove longest trailing #comment
 # a+=(                            )  # if append non-empty lines to array
<<<$#a                                # print array length
```

---

### [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-oextendedglob -oglobstarshort -oglobdots`, 51 bytes

```sh
for f (**.sh)a+=(${${(f)"$(<$f)"}/[ 	]#\#*})
<<<$#a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7LTsQwDDxvvmIgEX2gbSTOoTe48gEsh7R1txFtUiWWWLHaby9hQWDJHnvGHvkzTdvyPriI/YrG6k4L6qcAVfBEkWBz8kc4@Nl5SgXan6XGNmkSLboMMAbF08tzIeSN7pzXWZHow7KQZ4HfkEir7SmJnQTbLvO5WdyJBuEDZ9n@nUi4dCX@XbK9EIk4rAw6MfmBhuMcOnyXxDamKUS@TkPgtI0hYkRZ1/m/yt4/luqszuVY3arSqAwX/YrdmzzI@lIJY4ySdluj84z9DGXR3j1sXw)

globstarshort allows `**.sh`, globdots removes the `(D)` flag, and extendedglob makes `[ \t]#` work like the regex `[ \t]*`.

Sidenote: I think some answers here don't match hidden files. If they can be safely ignored, then `-oglobdots` or `(D)` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 114 bytes

```
import os,re
var c=0
for f in walkDirRec".":
 if f=~re".*\.sh$":
  for l in f.lines:c+=int l=~re"\s*[^#\s]"
echo c
```